# TFS Where to list approval comments

Tags: tfs, release-management

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 15.112.26307.0.

Using the Releases page/view for a group of approvers to review and manually trigger the release from environment QA to environment PROD (first environment triggers automatically).

From that screen, the approver clicks the icon and then in "override" to approve and launch second environment... on that action (popup) it asks for a comment and the the user clicks the approve button which triggers the next release environment... until here, its the standard way from TFS....

I wanted to know if there is a way to list all releases that completed all environments, and on that list show who approved it and also the comment entered... is it possible to customize a view or create a whole new list querying that information? Its a information/audit list only... no need to take action from there... just summarize the information for review.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Releases - Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) API to get the information you want. Since you are using TFS 2017 Update 1 RTM, you could capture the rest api by pressing `F12` in browser then select `Network`. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

I've tested the following api in Version 15.117.27414.0, and get the comments successfully:

```
Get 
http://tfs2017:8081/tfs/{collection}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks promising, I'll try with that

Comment: Yes, with that I get the json with all the release info